# Visual Studio 2013 not building my C# code into DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dll

I inherited a project that has source code(C#) which publishes into DLL files. I have updated a source code file and have built and published it but when I take the DLL file and decompile it to see if it has been successfully updated, I can see that the code has not changed at all. I feel as if there is a setting somewhere that I am missing that tells VS2013 to include or update the DLL when the C# code is modified or selected.

Thanks!

Comment: Compiling the code produces a new DLL with the compiled code in it.  I suspect there's something wrong with your deployment or validation process, outside the context of Visual Studio and C# entirely.

Comment: Isn't it enough to check the Date Modified attribute on the DLL file? Are you sure you're not doing a Debug build, but checking the Release folder or vice versa?

Comment: Please check your project output path. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms165410(v=vs.120).aspx and clean & rebuild

Comment: Clean the project and build it again.

Comment: @itsme86, The date attribute does change, its just like the specific c# file I am editing is excluded during the build and publish. I am using the Release configuration during the build and i have a folder specific for that build type.

Comment: @David A new DLL is produced as it is modified, what should I check?

Comment: @SteMa and Mangist, I cleaned and then rebuilt, same result.

Comment: Output path correct?

Comment: @SteMa, yes. I have it outputting(publish method) to a file system folder.